# Excel copy to specific sheet depending on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to copy text from my front sheet to a variant sheet.

What I want is to copy cells J19,J20,J21 to cells A1,B1,C1 of the different sheets. J19 decides which sheet to copy to as each *agent* has their own sheet which has a macro pulling the agent names into a data validation onto J19.

J19 = Agent Name

J20 = Holiday Start Date

J21 = Holiday End Date

How do I change    `Set wsDestin = Sheets("Agent1")`so that it looks at J19 to decide the destination cell.

```
Sub CopyColumnP()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestin As Worksheet
    Dim lngDestinRow As Long
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngCel As Range

    Set wsSource = Sheets("Front")
    Set wsDestin = Sheets("Agent1")

    With wsSource

        Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(19, "J"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each rngCel In rngSource
        If rngCel.Value = "Design" Then
            With wsDestin
                lngDestinRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                rngCel.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wsDestin.Cells(lngDestinRow, "A")
            End With
        End If
    Next rngCel
    End Sub
```

Comment: Cells("J19").Value

Comment: Is it really that simple? I thought it would be much more complex @Luuklag

Answer (score 1):

It's easy like this:

```
Set wsDestin = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsSource.Range("J19").Value)
```

To check if the sheet exists end prevent errors use:

```
On Error Resume Next
    Set wsDestin = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsSource.Range("J19").Value)
    If Not Err.Number = 0 Then 
        MsgBox "Sheet '" & wsSource.Range("A1").Value & "' not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

---

Or if J19 doesn't contain the destination worksheet name but you need to select a worksheet based on J19's value then use:

```
Select Case wsSource.Range("J19").Value
    Case "AAA" 'if value of J19 is AAA select sheet A
        Set wsDestin = Sheets("A")

    Case "B", "C" 'if value of J19 is B or C select sheet BC
        Set wsDestin = Sheets("BC")

    Case Else
        MsgBox "no corresponding worksheet found."
End Select
```

Comment: If im correct that would replace the contents of `J19`? I want the code to look at `J19` to decide which sheet to copy & paste the data from `J19,J20,21` to `A1,A2,A3` of the sheet name in `J19`.

Comment: Left of the equal sign will get the value that is on the right of the equal sign. You might want to explicitly reference a workbook here.

Comment: @JackBrownridge If J19 doesn't contain the destination worksheet name but you need to select a worksheet based on J19's value then use the second part of my answer.

Comment: @Peh yes J19 contains the destination worksheet name as the sheets are pulled into a data validation on that cell.

Comment: @JackBrownridge if you get an Error 9 then a sheet named like the value in J19 doesn't exist

Comment: J19 was blank before.. my bad - added the name but nothing happens when i click the button, is rest of the code correct to transfer it?

Comment: @JackBrownridge I added an error handling for non-existing sheets.

Comment: Have a look at [Debugging and Troubleshooting](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/861/debugging-and-troubleshooting) to learn how to debug a code and go through step by step so you see what happens.